# Is there a specific term for "tone of command" in English?

Tags: terminology, tone

I'm wondering if there is a specific word that refers to a "tone of command." I'm putting it in double quotations because in my native language (Korean) we have a specific word called "myung-nyung-jo" (for some reason the website won't let me write Korean) which literally translates to "commanding tone" but I can't think of anything in English.

I initially thought that it may be related to causative verbs, but that doesn't seem accurate as well. For example:

> 1. Could you find my glasses for me?
> 2. Find my glasses for me.

The second sentence would be the type of sentence I'm interested in. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second sentence is in the [imperative mood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperative_mood).

Answer (score 0):

There are 4 sentence types:

- Imperative- what you're asking for in your question, so a command/ instruction e.g. Cross the road, write that down (they don't have to be used in a bossy controlling way btw but can be used to imply that someone is bossy). You might be thinking about "bossy verbs" as we call them in sch aka "Imperative verbs" e.g. take, give, go, stop.
- Interrogative- questions e.g. how are you? what is that?
- Exclamative- end with an exclamation mark e.g. I'm so excited! Wow it's a real unicorn!
- Declarative- stating something e.g. that is a horse. I am smart. I think opinions such as "I think you're smart" also count as Declarative but I'm not 100%.

Look up sentence types on google. It might come up with compound, complex etc but the 4 I've just stated should come up aswell.
Hope this helps.
I'm from Britain so keep that in mind. Also not a professional.